# How to change an image every time box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm making a game where an image of a number appears every time you click on the box.

I am trying to change the background image every time the user clicks the box. There are nine images. Upon the first click, the image will change to `img/num1.png` etc. After the 9th click I want it to go back to the first image (`img/num1.png`). Is there a way to do this without getting a infinite loop?

Right now it gets to the 9th image and then stops. There will be four boxes that need to do this. Here is what I have:

```
var squareClicks = 0;

$('.numSquares').click(userPicksNum);

function userPicksNum()
{

    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {

    if (squareClicks == 1)
        {
            //when box is clicked set background image
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num1.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums();
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 2)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num2.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[2];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 3)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num3.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[3];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 4)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num4.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[4];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 5)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num5.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[5];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 6)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num6.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[6];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 7)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num7.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[7];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 8)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num8.png');
            squareClicks++
            checkNums[8];
        }

        else if (squareClicks == 9)
        {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/num9.png');
            checkNums[9];
            squareClicks++
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your entire code shown in your question with this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2m1ujg0/1)

```
  var squareClicks = 1;
$('.numSquares').click(userPicksNum);

function userPicksNum() {


    if (squareClicks == 10) {
        squareClicks = 1 } // resets your counter when the last image is reached
        alert(squareClicks);    // just for testing, remove this...     
        $(this).attr('src', 'img/num'+squareClicks+'.png'); //get's the correct img for you
        squareClicks++; //sets square clicks up


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question right, you can do 3 things:
1)Get rid of the for loop. 
2)At the last else if statement you can assign squareClicks =1;
3)Assign squareClicks to 1 at the beginning

Below is the version of code I have described above:

```
var squareClicks = 1;

$('.numSquares').click(userPicksNum);

 function userPicksNum()
 {

   if (squareClicks == 1)
   {
    //when box is clicked set background image
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num1.png');
    squareClicks++;

  }

   else if (squareClicks == 2)
   {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num2.png');
    squareClicks++;

   }

   else if (squareClicks == 3)
   {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num3.png');
    squareClicks++;

   }

 else if (squareClicks == 4)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num4.png');
    squareClicks++;

  }

  else if (squareClicks == 5)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num5.png');
    squareClicks++;

  }

  else if (squareClicks == 6)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num6.png');
    squareClicks++

  }

  else if (squareClicks == 7)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num7.png');
    squareClicks++;

  }

  else if (squareClicks == 8)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num8.png');
    squareClicks++;

  }

else if (squareClicks == 9)
  {
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/num9.png');
    squareClicks=1;
  }

}
```

Hope it helps!